# matplotlib. savefig() saves the image in the wrong folder

Tags: python, matplotlib

i got these line of codes, and i want to save the figure to an specific folder.

```
images = r"C:\Users\danie\Desktop\test"
plt.savefig( images + "test"+ ".png")
```

could anyone help me, why matplotlib is saving the figure to the Desktop but not in the folder, that's given in the path ?

Comment: Missing a backslash after the folder `test`.

Comment: Always use `os.path.join()` to build your path. Never write it by hand.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to put a `\` after folder `test`. When you substitute the image path, you will get something like `C:\Users\danie\Desktop\testtest.png"`. So now python thinks that the image should be saved as `C:\Users\danie\Desktop\testtest.png"` which you don't want. You want `C:\Users\danie\Desktop\test\test.png"`

Solution:

Just add a `\` after `test`

```
images = r"C:\Users\danie\Desktop\test\"
plt.savefig( images + "test"+ ".png")
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed to add \\  after test in the path. Now it works fine!